# Spring: How to use annotation as a parameter to another annotation?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am trying to do something like this

```
@Cacheevict(@Value("#{properties.cacheName}")
```

`Syntax wise`, this is wrong . Any other way to implement such functionality?

Answer (score 0):

For those annotation attributes that support SpEL it is documented in the [API documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/) and in such cases you can simply add the SpEL directly instead of wrapping it in another @Value annotation.

Unfortunatly the value attribute of the [@CacheEvict annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CacheEvict.html) doesn't support SpEL expressions and as such can only directly contain the names of the caches to evict.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario I think you should implement `CacheManager` interface for such non-static mapping of cache name to real cache.